# How to generate Hasse diagram for the given relations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, equivalence-relations

currently learning about hasse diagrams and equivalences.

given the following relations $ R_1,R_2,R_3$ how should I generate the Hasse diagram (could someone show me  how it would look like?).

I understand that only one of these relations is able to generate the Hasse (my guess is $R_3$ but correct me if I am wrong)

The set is made up of:

> {a, b, c, d, e, f}

[image: relations info]

I would assume I need the hasse diagram to find the minimal elements,lowest bound and upper bound elements.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $R_3$ is the only among these relations which is a partial ordering.

While they're all reflexive, $R_1$ is clearly not anti-symmetric; indeed, it's the equivalence relation with classes $\{a,c,f\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{d,e\}$.

Relation $R_2$ is also not anti-symmetric: for example $cR_2d$ and $dR_2c$.
On the other hand, it isn't symmetric either: $cR_2b$ but not the converse.
Hence $R_2$ is neither an equivalence relation, nor a partial order.

Finally, as you suspected, $R_3$ is a partial order.
Here's its Hasse diagram:

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! could I ask also how did you get the equivalence relation to be {a,c,f} , {b}, {d,e} ? :)

Comment: @MeganDarcy Well, I suppose that $xRy$ iff $M_{xy}=1$ (the matrix entry). The way I proceeded with each relation then was to place the elements in a graph (scattered in a hexagon shape) and make a graph with $x\to y$ iff $xRy$. In the case of $R_1$ this gives three blocks (the ones mentioned) in which each element is related to each other and to no element of another block. That's what an equivalence relation is, graphically. In the case of $R_3$ I had to delete the redundant arrows and arrange the elements according to the order.

Comment: i understand thank you! ^_^